# Solve works with numbers, but not with free variables

Tags: equation-solving

The following code prints the correct solution for variable `a` (2.23).

But if I comment out the five assignments given at the top, the code fails.
When I remove some of the constraints at the bottom (&& ...), I get various error messages or the code runs indefinitely.

What can I do to get the solution for `a`?

```
initVel = 0.2
initPos = 0.7
zeroAccPos = 1
posAtT = 0.546373
t = 0.6

c1pc2 = zeroAccPos - initPos
c1mc2 = -initVel/a
c1 = (c1pc2 + c1mc2)/2
c2 = (c1pc2 - c1mc2)/2

f1 = c1*Exp[a*t]
f2 = c2*Exp[-a*t]

possible = (initPos + initVel*t - posAtT)*(zeroAccPos - initPos)

Solve[posAtT == zeroAccPos - (f1 + f2) 
  && a > 0
  && t > 0
  && c1 > 0
  && c1pc2 != 0
  && initVel != 0
  && possible > 0 
 , a]
```

Comment: The equation is transcendental in `a`, so I doubt there is an analytic solution. I still don't get a solution for `a` when using the given values of the constants. Instead, `Solve` complains that "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients (...)". But using `FindRoot[posAtT == zeroAccPos - (f1 + f2), {a,1}]` works.

Comment: @Marius Thx, I think there is an analytic solution because at least there is one if initVel is zero. Mathematica finds it if i remove all constraints: initVel = 0
Solve[posAtT == zeroAccPos - (f1 + f2), a]

Comment: `Solve` only finds generic solutions, so unless you specify such specific cases then it won't find them. You could try to use `Reduce` with some interesting specific cases, but for the general equation, it cannot find solutions either.

Comment: Gosh how I wish people would be semicolons in to suppress irrelevant output...